# Writing to an empty file in c using a single program but running it more than once at the same time

Tags: shell, race-condition, file-locking

```
    #! /bin/sh
    # count2 also increments and appends a value to the numbers file
    # but only when it can successfully create a new hard link to the numbers file

    count=0
    while [ $count -lt 200 ]      # still loop 200 times
    do
       count=`expr $count + 1`    # increment the loop counter
       if ln numbers numbers.lock # try to enter the critical region
       then                       # in this case, ln is similar to TSL
          n=`tail -1 numbers`     # get the last number to increment
          expr $n + 1 >> numbers  # increment it and append it to the file
          rm numbers.lock         # exit the critical region
       fi                         # Note that if the ln was unsuccessful, we don't
                              # do busy waiting, but just continue looping
    done
```

My task is to implement the following shellscript in c but I have know idea how to implement the line that says " if ln numbers numbers.lock # try to enter the critical region" 
in c. What the script does is that it counts to 200 hundred and outputs it to a file counting the numbers from 1-200... I know how to do that but the tricky part is to run a c program implementing this but running the same instance of the program multiple times at the same time. Which means all programs will try to write to the same file giving a very unorderly output like: 1 1 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3 4 4 4 for example! A fix is to implement a lock so that a program accessing the resource cannot be interfered until its done executing, when it is done the next program can use the resource while it was running in the 'background'. How do I do this? Or how do I replicate that specific line of code ? Any references to useful resources will be appreciated and I have been searching but I just end up reading complicated stuff in c and I am not that experienced in c programming. To make the question clear: How to implement that do loop in with the locking where the locking is my main concern. THANKS!

Answer (score 1):

In this snippet, the mutual exclusivity is achieved by creating a hardlink (which can be assumed to be atomic). If you want to mimic that in C, you might want to take a look at the [`link(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/link.2.html) POSIX function.

A return value of `-1` indicates failure. However, even though the script doesn't do that, it is a good idea to also check `errno` to see if the failure is really caused by the link already existing (i.e., another instance of the program being in the critical section, indicated by `errno == EEXIST`), to prevent infinite loops if something else is wrong (e.g., read-only file system).

And for removing that link when exiting the critical section, [`unlink(2)`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/unlink.2.html) is your friend.

Answer (score 0):

A simple and adequate way would be to write this in your C code:

```
 int result = system("ln numbers numbers.lock")
```

If the return value is 0, then it succeeded in creating the link, which means it has acquired the lock in your scheme.

Alternatively, you might consider moving away from using symbolic links as locks, and using the [flock system call](http://linux.die.net/man/2/flock) instead.  The way it works is that you would open the file in your C program, then call `flock` to lock it.

Comment: 3 remarks: 1) ln creates hard links by default, not symbolic links (ln -s creates symlinks) 2) using the link system call as suggested by @misberner is a lot less heavy handed than shelling out and 3) flock is indeed a very nice alternative, just be cautious if the solution should work on shared (nfs) filesystems with older Linux kernels.

Comment: Thanks, I'll fix up the answer to address #1.

Answer (score 0):

Here is small flock implementation in c under linux. Explanation is given in code comments. 
Also for more info on OS, I recommend famous APUE book.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <string.h>

#define LOCK_FILE "lock.txt"

void error_fatal (const char *message){
  perror (message);
  exit (EXIT_FAILURE);
}

/* we demonstrate file locking. (Mandatory locking) */

int main(){
  int fd,i;
  char str[10];
  struct flock lock;

  /* Open the file. (fd is file-descriptor) */
  if ( (fd = open (LOCK_FILE, O_WRONLY | O_CREAT, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR | S_IRGRP | S_IROTH)) < 0)
    error_fatal ("open error");

  /* Here we initialize lock values based on our usecase
     in our case we want write lock and we want lock to cover whole file.
     (file region) */
  lock.l_type = F_WRLCK;
  lock.l_whence = SEEK_SET;
  lock.l_start = 0;
  lock.l_len = 0;

  /* We try to set the lock */
  if (fcntl (fd, F_SETLK, &lock) < 0){

    /* Case when there is another instance already running */
    if (errno == EACCES || errno == EAGAIN){
      printf ("Another instance already running.\n");
      exit (EXIT_SUCCESS);
    }
    else
      error_fatal ("fcntl error");
  } 


  /* Write numbers from 1 to 10 for demonstration. */   
  for(i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
    sprintf(str, "%d", i);
    write(fd, str, strlen(str));
    /* After each write, sleep */
    sleep(1);
  } 

  /* This program is set to sleep after each write (i sec) and in this timeframe we should execute another instance of program to see if locking is successful.

   Check lock.txt file to see number ordering.

  */


  return 0;
}
```